# Why can't I use str variables in input("text")?

Tags: string, python-3.x, variables, input

Tried to make a luck wheel calculator as a mission in class, through the use of str inputs varibles.

Example:

```
int(input("In which day of",a(defiend as a month inputed before),"were you born?"))
```

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please provide some (indented) code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it this way. You will get an error which says it all, input takes only one (!) argument. This is not print():

```
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3
```

Does this helps you? I make use of the new f-Strings introduced in Python 3.7!

```
month = "april"
day = int(input(f"In which day of {month} were you born? "))
print(f"{day}. {month}")
```

If you used an earlier Python version you will have to use .format(...):

```
month = "april"
day = int(input("In which day of {} were you born? ".format(month)))
print("{}. {}".format(day, month))
```

Happy pythoning.

Comment: `int(input("In which day of" + month + "were you born? ")`

Comment: Please add this as a second answer.

Maybe Tomer Bitran wants to delete his question. It damages his reputation!

Comment: I still don't know whether that is the answer OP is looking for or not. And in any case if it is, you have given very good examples.